# Why did my ChildNodes return undefined on JS event handler?

Tags: javascript

I am adding click handler into one of table elements. I confirmed it on inspect -> console that this is the returns the value that I need, the address value.

```
document.getElementById('donut-attributes').parentNode.childNodes[10].childNodes[1].childNodes[30].innerText 
//returns 123 Some Address on console log
```

This is the complete script on main page:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var donutContainer = document.getElementById("donut-attributes");
  donutContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert(e.target.parentNode);
    address = e.target.parentNode.childNodes[10].childNodes[1].childNodes[30].innerText;
    alert("donut container after");
    });
  }
</script>
```

I set up several `alert()` to make sure everything works. When it comes down to `alert(e.target.parentNode)`, it shows `[object HTMLTableRowElement]`. However, when it comes down to `alert(e.target.parentNode.childNodes[10]);`, it returns `undefined`.

How can I fix the click handler so when I click any table element, I would get the address value stored into `address`? Why does it show the address on console log and it shows `undefined` when I used it with clickhandler?

---

**EDIT**: the table html `(index.html.erb)` looks something like this:

```
  <table border=1 class="table table-condensed donut-attributes">
      <tbody class="table-hover">
          <tr>
            <td rowspan=5>
              Some_image
            </td>

              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">Some_name</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">Some_phone</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">Some_rating</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle" id="address" >Some_address</td>
              </tr>

                        <tr>
            <td rowspan=5>
              Some_image2
            </td>

              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">Some_name2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">Some_phone2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">Some_rating2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle" id="address" >Some_address2</td>
              </tr>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
```

How can I hover on any element on a table row, click it, and get the corresponding address? (i.e. if I hover and click on the **second** row, on **any** column in the second row, I need it to return some_address2)

Comment: `childNodes` includes whitespace text nodes, and comment nodes between elements in counting. Use `.children`

Comment: you probably want e.currentTarget as opposed to e.target. having said that, surely there's a better way to get at the element you want

Comment: When you say `address` in table, do you mean like the Battleship Game? ex. Column 3 Row 8?

Comment: `e.target.parentNode.cells[10]` would be most appropriate for accessing a table cell *(assuming the `.parentNode` is the row)*. However, since we don't have your actual rendered markup, we can't really know the issue.

Comment: @zer00ne, I am storing the result of the query. The app supposed to display a table with address as one of them (`"123 New York St, NY, 12345"`).  I then pass the variable `address` to be used on other part of the app. I am having trouble getting the specific address element

Comment: Well, the `td` you want the text of has an `id`, so why not use it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're repeating that ID on the page. Am I right?

Comment: Your line that starts with `document.getElementById('donut-attributes').parentNode` at the top of your question is inherently different than the one that starts with `e.target.parentNode...`

Comment: correct. It is a Rails app, on index page specifically. I have several elements in the array. Let's say I have `@donuts` with donut store address1, donut store address2, donut store address3. I want it to return `donut store address2` when I click `donut store address2` on the page.

Comment: Duplicate `id` values are not allowed in HTML.

Comment: Oh man! I forgot about that. Let me change that to class and see if it works.

Comment: *"...I want it to return `donut store address2` when I click `donut store address2` on the page."* So you basically want to get the TD in which you clicked?

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that. I want it to return donut store address 2 when I click any element of donut store2. I can click on the donut store image2, donut store name2, or donut store address2 - and it should return `donut store address2`

Comment: So if you click anywhere on a row, get the address for that row. Sound right?

Comment: how do we know what you mean with image, name, when none of that is in your question? Can you edit your question and add the missing information?

Comment: @squint correct. Return address when clicked anywhere in that; and I will update it right now - thanks!

Comment: Oh wait, so there's actually one "address" in each `tbody`, which is a grouping of multiple rows? It really would be better if you provided the rendered HTML.

Comment: `div` tags cannot be children of `tr` tags.

Comment: `.childNodes[10].childNodes[1].childNodes[30]` seems really bad design... Can't you add a class or name to select? And you can not have a div as child in a table's row. That is not valid HTML.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, and include tags for other technologies you are using. The provided HTML is not valid, and therefore we cannot reproduce this on our own.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it again. I included an HTML that somewhat mimics what it would look like on my display. I kept the `class` and `id` names. Thank you for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate values for the `id` attribute are not allowed in HTML, so you should remove that attribute from the `td` with `id="address"`, since it gets repeated.

To identify the "last" row in the group, you could reason that this row has a row index (zero-based) of 4, plus a multiple of 5. Or in other words, it is 4 modulo 5. Once you know the row index of the row that is being clicked in, it is not so hard to find the next row that has such an index:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var donutContainer = document.getElementById("donut-attributes");
  donutContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // Get the clicked element
    var el = e.target;
    // Find row that contains (or is) the clicked element
    while (el.tagName !== 'TR') {
        if (el === this) return; // give up
        el = el.parentNode;
    }
    // Get last row within group of rows
    el = this.rows[el.rowIndex - el.rowIndex % 5 + 4];
    // Get its text
    address = el.cells[0].textContent;
    alert(address);
  });
});
```

```css
table, td {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<table id="donut-attributes" class="table table-condensed">
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=5>[image 1]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">name1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">phone1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">rating1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">address1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=5>[image 2]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">name2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">phone2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">rating2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="center" style="vertical-align: middle">address2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that if you have a special header row in your table, or other rows that do not follow the multiple-of-five pattern, the formula has to be adapted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Updated so now it does exactly what OP needed, so if a `<tbody>` is clicked, we will get the text of the `td.address`that resides within it. In the source is a "lynchpin" comment added to alter the `extractData()` function so that it'll collect the text of whatever is clicked. Details are commented in the Snippet's code.

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>00A00</title>
  <style>
    table.X {
      padding: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 9px 1px #ccc;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    .X th {
      color: #FFF;
      background: #FA768E;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .X tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #FA768E;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    .X tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #D3E9FF;
      color: #F9F;
    }
    .X td {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #FA768E;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .X thead th:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    }
    .X thead th:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    .X tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    }
    .X tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    .X thead+tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
    }
    .X thead+tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    .X tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    }
    .X tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    .X tbody td.center.center {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .X tbody a {
      color: #121;
    }
    .a {
      background: #FEDAE0;
    }
    .rating {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    .col2 {
      color: #Fed;
      background: #123;
    }
    .X tr:nth-child(even) td.col2 {
      background: #Edf;
      color: #325;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="toons" class="table table-condensed X">
    <tbody class="table-hover" data-lvl='1'>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan='5' class='col1'>
          <img src='http://iconshow.me/media/images/ui/app-ui-icon/png/128/donut.png' class: 'thumbnail' style='margin-bottom:50px;'>
          <img src='http://icons.veryicon.com/png/Movie%20%26%20TV/Simpsons%204/Homer%20Simpson%2001%20Donut.png' class='thumbnail' style='width:200px;height:200px;'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="link center col1"><a href='https://www.facebook.com/HurtsDonutCompany'>Hurt's Donut Company</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="phone center col1">417.300.6106</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="rating center col1">&#11088;&#11088;&#11088;&#11088;&#11088;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="address center col1">320 Park Central W.
          <br>Springfield, Missouri, USA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="table-hover">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan='5' class='col2'>
          <img src='http://imgh.us/space-donut.gif' class: 'thumbnail' style='margin-bottom:50px;width:200px;'>
          <img src='http://imgh.us/gir_zim.gif' class='thumbnail' style='width:200px;height:200px;'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="link center col2"><a href='https://training.gov.au/Training/Details/FDFRB3014A'>Fried Yeast Products</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="phone center col2">&#43640;&#4175;&#128784;&#128883;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="rating center col2">&#127758;&#127758;&#127758;&#127758;&#127758;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="address center col2">WarpGate U812
          <br>Horsehead Nebula, Irk</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    // Collect and reference every <tbody>
    var T = document.querySelectorAll('tbody');

     // For each <tbody>...
    [].forEach.call(T, function(t, idx) {

      /* When any part of the <tbody> is clicked...
    || ...function extractData() is called
    */
      T[idx].addEventListener('click', extractData, false);

    });

    /* extractData() will pass an event object...
  || ...and using it's properties to find...
  || ...event.target (the node that was clicked)...
  || ...Next we store the event.target in a var...
  || ...and check to see if it has the class .address...
  || ...if it doesn't, we will find the <tbody> ...
  || ...that it belongs to. From there we'll find...
  || ...td.address and get it's text content...
  || ...Otherwise if we had clicked the td.address...
  || ...we'll have the text already.
  */
    function extractData(event) {
      if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
        var dataSource = event.target;

        //* Remove a '/' to get the exact text of each <td>
        if (!dataSource.classList.contains('address')) {
          var grandma = dataSource.closest('tbody');
         console.log(grandma.querySelector('.address').textContent);
        } else //*/
          console.log(dataSource.textContent);

      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the markup (HTML), each "subject" is in it's own `<tbody>` this helps us to not only to organize the data better, it also facilitates DOM transversal as well. Having multiple `<tbody>` is completely valid as well.